# Is There Some Sort Of Health Or Scientific Reason That Explains The Benefit Of Eating Animals With A Divided Hoofs?

Tags: moses, leviticus, torah, israel

And the Lord spake unto Moses and to Aaron, saying unto them,

2 Speak unto the children of Israel, saying, These are the beasts which ye shall eat among all the beasts that are on the earth.

3 Whatsoever parteth the hoof, and is clovenfooted, and cheweth the cud, among the beasts, that shall ye eat.(Leviticus 11:1-3)

I understand the book of Leviticus 11 says that its ok to eat animals with divvied hoofs and if it chews the Cud. My question is particularly dealing with the divided hoofs. Is there a scientific reason or some sort of health reason as to why animals with divided hoofs(along with it chewing the cud) is ok to consume? I understand the benefits for consuming an animal that chews the cud but not the reason behind the divided hoofs. Since this is the dietary law, I am assuming that all of these things are for mainly health reasons.

Comment: These things were for spiritual reasons. Chewing the cud is a matter of eating that which is within (Christ being formed within) - the tree has seed within itself. And a divided hoof represents that there are two ways to walk in this world : by the tree of life or by the knowledge of good and evil, and a discerning beast will walk accordingly. I very much doubt you will find a medical or dietary reason but I am up-voting you as an encouragement in your endeavors. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Some of the kosher requirements are for animals that are strict vegetarians.  For example, feeding cows feed containing meat from cows caused mad cow disease to spread.  Pigs are omnivorous by nature.   However, the split hoof requirement eliminates easing horses.

Comment: This is a "can we find scientific reasons to support the Bible?" question not a "what does the Bible say/mean?" question. If the question were "Is there anything in the Bible that explains the health benefits of the dietary laws?" it would be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small excerpt from a 66 page booklet about general principles of health, as taught in the Bible:

> #### Stay on the Grass!
>
> Leviticus 11 and Deuteronomy 14 are the primary passages in the Bible that describe the dietary laws.
> These chapters provide very specific information summarized in simple, easy-to-understand principles that could be applied long before the microscope was invented,
> and long before germ theory was proposed.
> Today, the discoveries of modern science are revealing just how important and practical these laws really are.
>
> Beginning in Leviticus 11, we read that God told Moses and Aaron to inform the Israelites, “These are the animals which you may eat
> among all the animals that are on the earth: Among the animals, whatever divides the hoof, having cloven hooves and chewing the cud—that
> you may eat” (vv. 1–3).
> Plant-eating mammals (herbivores) that fit this description are called ruminants.
> These animals have four-chambered stomachs that convert grasses that are inedible to humans and other animals into nutritious, high-quality protein products (meat and milk) that people can then use for food.
> Examples of clean animals would be all cattle, sheep, goats, deer, bison, moose, antelope, gazelles, caribou,
> and giraffes.
> They are all divided-hoof herbivores that obtain their food by grazing or browsing on grasses and other plants.
>
> From the standpoint of wise environmental management, these guidelines make a lot of sense.
> Vast areas of the globe are covered by rangelands (savannas, veldts, and pampas), which are often called “marginal lands” because they do not have enough rainfall to support the production of food crops like corn or wheat.
> “Cattle, sheep and goats have the ability to convert plant carbohydrates and proteins into available nutrients for human use, making otherwise unusable land productive.”
>
> The clean animals that God permitted His model nation to eat — easily discerned by split hooves and cud-chewing—were designed to produce nutritious food in an economical and ecologically sound manner.
> These guidelines were a key benefit that God wanted the world to see through the example of Israel.
>
> — [Biblical Principles of Health | Living Church of God](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/biblical-principles-of-health)

The booklet is well worth reading for its various other topics related to health.

Here's part of another organization's booklet that deals in much more detail specifically about clean and unclean food:

> #### Health risk to humans?
>
> Dr. Russell asks, “What is so good about ‘clean’ meats, and what is so bad about ‘unclean’ meats?”
> He goes on to explain that “the flesh of clean animals such as beef, and fish that have scales and fins, is ideal
> for the health of humans—just as we would expect from the hand of a loving Creator …
> Many land animals God designed for food provide an additional benefit in that they generally eat grasses and grains that were
> also designed for food” (Russell, pp. 73-74).
>
> In contrast, David Meinz summarizes the potential health risk of eating creatures the Bible classifies as unclean.
> “Almost all of the creatures on the unclean list are scavengers,” he notes.
> “In many cases they don’t hunt for their own food; they eat the dead and decaying matter of our environment.
> A catfish does that at the bottom of a pond; lobsters and shrimp do it in the ocean.
> A pig will eat anything. Vultures, almost by definition, are known for their scavenger habits” (Meinz, p. 225).
>
> Dr. Russell notes that “an animal doesn’t have to be a scavenger to be unclean.
> Horses and rabbits, for example, are unclean because they do not have split hooves.
> Although they are considered to be good food in some countries, studies have shown that horse meat often contains viruses and parasites.
> Rabbits, as innocent as they appear, are the cause of tularemia (an infectious disease) in humans.
>
> “One reason for God’s rule forbidding pork is that the digestive system of a pig is completely different from that of a cow.
> It is similar to ours, in that the stomach is very acidic.
> Pigs are gluttonous, never knowing when to stop eating.
> Their stomach acids become diluted because of the volume of food, allowing all kinds of vermin to pass through this protective barrier.
> Parasites, bacteria, viruses and toxins can pass into the pig’s flesh because of overeating.
> These toxins and infectious agents can be passed on to humans when they eat a pig’s flesh” (Russell, p. 76-77).
>
> Don Colbert, M.D., adds: “Besides being gluttons, swine are also extremely filthy animals.
> They will eat garbage, feces, and even decaying flesh.
> All that is eaten usually becomes part of the pig’s own flesh …
> Aside from the diseases routinely carried by swine, pork is also a very fatty meat.
> The toxins in pork are held especially in the fat, which is not isolated from the meat as can be the case in lean beef, but rather, it is
> dispersed throughout the meat” (What Would Jesus Eat?, 2002, pp. 49-50).
>
> #### Poison on a plate?
>
> Dr. Russell’s supporting evidence for his views isn’t for the faint of heart.
> He writes: “In the United States, three of the six most common food-borne parasitic diseases of humans are associated with pork consumption.
> These include toxoplasmosis, taeniasis or cysticercosis (caused by the pork tapeworm Taenia solium) and trichinellosis …
>
> “It has long been recognized that the meat of shellfish—shrimp, crabs, lobsters, etc.—is especially dangerous.
> Many illnesses, including instant paralysis, devastate some people every day as a result of eating shellfish.
>
> “The largest cholera outbreak in the United States occurred in Louisiana from August through October 1986.
> (The symptoms of cholera are explosive diarrhea, leading to rapid dehydration, unconsciousness, hypotension and death.)
> What did the stricken people eat?
> The incriminating meals were found to include rice noodles with shrimp, pork, vegetables, mussel soup, pig blood coagulated with vinegar, and salty brine shrimp with mixed vegetables.
>
> “Shellfish can be placed in a body of water that is contaminated with cholera bacteria, and they will purify the water.
> Shrimp, oysters, crab, scallops and mussels are particularly efficient at this.
> They filter large volumes of water every day.
> Sewage laden with chemicals, toxins and harmful bacteria, parasites and viruses become concentrated in those shellfish.
> The cause of cholera outbreaks in several areas has been traced to contaminated shrimp, crab, oysters and clams.
>
> “Reading all this, you might not be surprised to learn that the state Legislature of California proposed a law requiring the food
> industry to label shellfish with a message warning: ‘This food may be dangerous to your health.’
> Why?
> In a single year, 50 deaths and many hospitalizations were found to have been caused by eating shellfish” (Russell, pp. 78-79).
>
> #### What purpose do they serve?
>
> If such creatures weren’t designed to be eaten, why did God create them?
> Dr. Russell explains: “For one thing, they serve a useful role just cleaning up the place.
> Many unclean animals, however, notably pigs and shellfish, are unhealthy because their diet consists of society’s diseaseladen refuse.
>
> “Pigs have eaten Philadelphia’s garbage and sewage for more than 100 years, saving the city $3 million a year in landfill costs.
> This is a wise use of hogs.
> They are designed to clean our environment.
>
> “Even when stacked in cages, piglets thrive on offal when only the pig in the top cage receives food.
> Farmers have increased their profits by feeding free raw sewage to pigs.
> Chicken farmers often keep a hog so they can dispose of dead chickens without having to bury them” (Russell, p. 81).
>
> Some species of fish and shellfish perform a similar role in the water.
> Dr. Russell notes that “among commonly eaten fish, catfish…always show the highest levels of contamination in chemically polluted water.
> After
> chemical spills, local fishermen are warned not to eat catfish” (ibid.).
>
> Even commercially raised catfish are a potential health risk, he notes.
> “Consumer Reports tested fish bought in multiple markets in the United States.
> Fish are considered spoiled when bacteria counts are greater than 10 million per gram of flesh.
> Nearly all catfish had counts that went off the scale at 27 million per gram, even when properly prepared” (ibid.).
>
> Dr. Russell’s conclusion?
> “Although swine help clean the earth, and shellfish and catfish are ideally designed to purify the water, we don’t want to eat what they clean up!” (ibid.)
>
> In light of such seldom-publicized facts, we can better understand and appreciate God’s words through Moses: “Observe and obey all these words which I command you, that it may go well with you and your children after you forever, when you do what is good and right in the sight of the Lord your God” (Deuteronomy 12:28).
>
> May we all be careful to “discern between the unclean and the clean” (Ezekiel 44:23).
>
> — [What Does the Bible Teach About Clean and Unclean Meats? pp. 28–31 | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/what-does-the-bible-teach-about-clean-and-unclean-meats)

Comment: Excellent response, +1.  I know of a doctor who practiced in Central America and realized over time when asking his patients what they had eaten before becoming ill that they had almost always had some unclean meat--snake, monkey, pork, etc.  They almost never sickened after eating beef or chicken.